# Fiberglass insulation that didn't cause skin irritation?

Tags: insulation

I had to move around some insulation in my basement to find the cause of a leak. The insulation is yellow and fluffy, so I'm assuming it's fiberglass. I wasn't wearing gloves or eye protection, but I didn't end up itching or anything. My house was built in 2006.

Is it likely fiberglass and I was I just lucky to not get skin irritation?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Fiberglass doesn't bother me either when I work with it for a short period of time. However, if I work with it long enough, I'll find it in my shorts, and that drives me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insulation is almost certainly fiberglass.

Fiberglass has evolved over the years. In the 70s it was very coarse and caused much discomfort after even brief, light contact. The manufacturing process has been refined to result in longer and thinner fibers, which tend to irritate much less. Still, it's advisable to wear protective clothing and to wash with cool water and soap after contact.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of fiberglass that is yellow. I have yellow fiberglass in my attic [not dissimilar to this](https://www.familyhandyman.com/walls/how-to-install-fiberglass-batt-insulation/view-all)

[image]

More people are familiar with Owens Corning and their pink fiberglass (they advertise heavily and have licensed the Pink Panther as their mascot). Johns & Mansville (typically sold at Lowes) is [brownish in color](https://www.jm.com/en/home-insulation/products/fiber-glass/unfaced-batts-androlls/)

[image]

Keep in mind that fiberglass takes time for the fibers to work into your skin. I often don't feel it until I shower afterward